# Need some help with Twitter/Blackbird Pie

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I'm having a lot of trouble working through the API for Blackbird Pie, especially since their API isn't actually an API but is apparently just a blog.

[Here's](http://media.twitter.com/tag/api) the API link from Blackbird Pie.

I want to be able to take in a unique tweet link that a user enters into my MySQL database and output them to a page using a query and PHP but I'm not really sure how to go about doing this. Searches just reveal methods for embedding tweets manually which is not what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like stackoverflow shies away from twitter posts haha

Comment: Note: this kind of questions are too localized, too specific and too vague to be answered any time soon. Asking for advice: see Programmers Stack Exchange. Please improve your question: what is the problem, specifically? What have you tried to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Pindatjuh makes a good point. So if I'm understanding this your basicly building a twitter feed, but you don't want it to display via json or xml from twitter. You could write a little phpscript to scrape the info and before you throw it into the database have them confirm if the information is correct. If I'm understanding you correctly you might want to check out this scraper for IMDB.

http://web3o.blogspot.com/2010/10/php-imdb-scraper-for-new-imdb-template.html

You could probably modify it to your needs.

One more suggestion is the json feed I wrote. Instead of echoing the output you could throw it into the database.

[PHP JSON Twitter Feed Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180858/php-json-twitter-feed-improvement)

Hope this gives you somewhere to start! Happy Coding.